# Creating Lookup based on user defined ranges

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, runtime-error, xlookup

I'm certain I am overlooking something simple but I just can't figure it this morning. I am attempting to simulate a XLookup for users with VBA code. Folks I work with have a range of excel skills and some just have a really hard time with this formula.

My code prompts the users to define all relevant ranges but when the lookup itself is returning Error 9.

```
Sub Lookup()

Dim invRange, lkRange, rtnRange, outRange As Range
Dim strInput, invPrompt, invTitle, lkPrompt, lkTitle, rtnPrompt, rtnTitle, outPrompt, outTitle As String
Dim invArray, lkArray, rtnArray, outArray As Variant
Dim x, j, i, k As Integer
Dim txt As String
ReDim invRange(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
invPrompt = "Select the Invoices you wish to look up."
invTitle = "Select Lookup Value"
lkPrompt = "Select the column where you wish to lookup the Invoices."
lkTitle = "Select Lookup Range"
rtnPrompt = "Select the column where you wish to return data from."
rtnTitle = "Select Return Range"
outPrompt = "Select the column where you wish to output the data."
outTitle = "Select Output Range"
On Error Resume Next
' Invoice Range Selection Input Box
Set invRange = Application.InputBox( _
    Prompt:=invPrompt, _
    Title:=invTitle, _
    Default:=Selection.Address, _
    Type:=8) 'Range selection
If invRange Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
' Turns Range into Array or Exits sub if no range was selected
invArray = Application.Transpose(invRange.Value)
If IsArray(invArray) = False Then
    invArray = Array(invArray)
End If
For x = 0 To UBound(invArray)
    invArray(x) = Replace(invArray(x), Chr(160), " ")
    invArray(x) = RTrim(invArray(x))
Next
' Lookup Range Selection Input Box
Set lkRange = Application.InputBox( _
    Prompt:=lkPrompt, _
    Title:=lkTitle, _
    Default:=Selection.Address, _
    Type:=8) 'Range selection
If lkRange Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
' Turns Range into Array or Exits sub if no range was selected
lkArray = Application.Transpose(lkRange.Value)
If IsArray(lkArray) = False Then
    lkArray = Array(lkArray)
End If
For j = 0 To UBound(lkArray)
    lkArray(j) = Replace(lkArray(j), Chr(160), " ")
    lkArray(j) = RTrim(lkArray(j))
Next
' Return Range Selection Input Box
Set rtnRange = Application.InputBox( _
    Prompt:=rtnPrompt, _
    Title:=rtnTitle, _
    Default:=Selection.Address, _
    Type:=8) 'Range selection
If rtnRange Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
' Turns Range into Array or Exits sub if no range was selected
rtnArray = Application.Transpose(rtnRange.Value)
If IsArray(rtnArray) = False Then
    rtnArray = Array(rtnArray)
End If
For i = 0 To UBound(rtnArray)
    rtnArray(i) = Replace(rtnArray(i), Chr(160), " ")
    rtnArray(i) = RTrim(rtnArray(i))
Next
' Output Range Selection Input Box
Set outRange = Application.InputBox( _
    Prompt:=outPrompt, _
    Title:=outTitle, _
    Default:=Selection.Address, _
    Type:=8) 'Range selection
If outRange Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
' Turns Range into Array or Exits sub if no range was selected
outArray = Application.Transpose(outRange.Value)
If IsArray(outArray) = False Then
    outArray = Array(outArray)
End If
For k = 0 To UBound(outArray)
    outArray(k) = Replace(outArray(k), Chr(160), " ")
    outArray(k) = RTrim(outArray(k))
Next
On Error GoTo 0
'Lookup each item from LookupValue array
 For i = 1 To UBound(invArray)
    For j = 1 To UBound(lkArray)
            If invArray(i, 1) = lkArray(j, 1) Then
                outArray(i, 1) = rtnArray(j, 1)
            Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
outArray.Resize(UBound(outArray, 1), 1).Value = outArray
End Sub
```

Comment: You don't need to `Transpose`, but if you do, the lower bound of the array is `1`, not `0`.

Comment: `outArray.Resize(UBound(outArray, 1), 1).Value = outArray` --- shouldn't the first `outArray` be `outRange`?

Comment: When you do `Range.Value` for a multicell range, it creates a 2 dimensional array. `invarray(x)` is causing an error because the array is expecting 2 indexes, but you're only providing one. You need `invarray(x,y)` or something similar. And do the same for all the other arrays.

Comment: Mixing 2D arrays with 1D arrays will require almost an entirely separate set of code to handle each case. `Range.Value` is giving 2D arrays and `invArray = Array(invArray)` is giving 1D arrays. You will need to check for the dimensions of the array or it will give errors.